# Bootstrap containers of different types wrapped in another elements with css width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, containers

I'm new in bootstrap and I don't know if it's possible to have bootstrap containers wrapped in another element, Or if that wrapper can have some width, something like this,

```
<div style="background:url('xycv.jpg') center top no-repeat; width:100%">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">col1</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">col2</div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="background:url('bla.png') center top no-repeat; width:100%">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">col1</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">col2</div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or what happens if wrapper will have width:950px?

Answer (score 0):

`.container-fluid` itself behaves like your wrapper, so your wrapper is kind of obsolete. Setting the `background` on the `.container-fluid` is what I would do.

If you need to wrap some bootstrap elements in your own element, you sure can do this.

Comment: Ok 100%width is obsolete but is it possible to set wrapper to width:950px and container get inside of it?

Comment: As long as it is .container-fluid, yes. .container-fluid is set to 100% width by bootstrap. .container is set to a specific width and will most likely not work with your custom wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can have, only in case when you are using `container-fluid` class.

Comment: Can be more specific? .container-fluid yes but .container not? Be wrapped? Be wrapped with widht?

Comment: yes only in container-fluid case you can use, because while dealing with container class bootstrap will provide the specific width in px value.